# Destroying game object destroys additional object

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am building a simple hyper casual game and faced a strange issue when destroying one object destroyes another not related object.

[image]

As you can see when white cube collides with black rectangle, cube is destroyed(which is expected) and also one more rectangle is destroyed(first from the top, and it is not expected).

```
public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour {

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed;

    private void Awake() {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

code for white cube

```
public class PlayerUnit : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

code for Input controller

```
public class TouchManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private float moveSpeed;

[SerializeField]
private PlayerInput playerInput;

private InputAction touchPositionAction;
private InputAction touchPressAction;

private Vector2 direction = Vector2.left;

private void Start() {
    touchPressAction = playerInput.actions["TouchPress"];
    touchPositionAction = playerInput.actions["TouchPosition"];

    touchPressAction.performed += TouchPressAction_performed;
}

private void OnDisable() {
    touchPressAction.performed -= TouchPressAction_performed;
}

private void Update() {
    transform.Translate(direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void TouchPressAction_performed(InputAction.CallbackContext context) {
    Vector2 value = touchPositionAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    direction = value.x < Camera.main.pixelWidth / 2 ? Vector2.left : Vector2.right;
}
}
```

Obstacle Generator

```
public class ObstaclesGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject leftWall;
private Transform leftWallBorderPoint;

private GameObject rightWall;
private Transform rightWallBorderPoint;

private Transform yPoint;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject obstacle;

private float minXObstacleSize = 1.5f;

private float maxXObstacleSize = 3f;

private float cooldown;

private void Awake() {
    this.leftWall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LeftWall");
    this.rightWall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("RightWall");

    this.leftWallBorderPoint = leftWall.transform.Find("Border");
    this.rightWallBorderPoint = rightWall.transform.Find("Border");

    this.yPoint = transform.Find("ObstacleGenerationPoint");
}

void Update() {
    if (cooldown <= 0) {
        cooldown = Random.Range(1f, 2f);

        GenerateObstacle();
    } else {
        cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void GenerateObstacle() {
    int random = Random.Range(0, 2);

    // choose obstacle side (left / right)
    float xCoord = random == 0 ? leftWallBorderPoint.position.x : rightWallBorderPoint.position.x;
    Vector3 instantiationPoint = new Vector3(xCoord / 1.3f, yPoint.transform.position.y, 0);

    GameObject instantiatedObstacle = Instantiate(obstacle, instantiationPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    // randomize obstacle size
    instantiatedObstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(minXObstacleSize, maxXObstacleSize), instantiatedObstacle.transform.localScale.y, 0);
} 
}
```

Reference remover (isTrigger)

```
public class ObstaclesReferenceRemover : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

My Unity Scene
[image]

Right and left walls -> simple rectangles with just sprite renderers.
Main road -> simple 2d rectangle

Scipts -> empty object
ObstacleGenerator -> empty with ObstacleGenerator script
ObstacleGenerationPoint -> empty object simply to have a ref point to instantiate obstacles

Player -> contains box collider 2D, rigidbody, TouchManagerScript and PlayerUnit.

Input -> contains input system reference

Obstacle reference remover -> just wide rectangle which acts as trigger, when obstacle reaches it, it gets destroyed.

Comment: Please create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Right now what we have is not complete because we don't see the code to generate and destroy obstacles. If this problem can be reproduced in a project without those scripts, that will also make the example more minimal.

Comment: Updated my question, basically that's all that there is.
@DMGregory

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and am by no means an expert, but when you destroy the collision for the cube as you did with the destroy.gameobject
shouldn't the variable be under the public class of PlayerUnit and not ObstaclesReferenceRemover?   Maybe we need a separate code to remove that reference after the cube is destroyed to clear the screen so to speak. right now it looks to me like they both get destroyed because of that. But, i'm new and i could be dead wrong.

Comment: Hi Gideon, I didn't get your comment.

RefereceRemoved is just a garbage collector that destroys obstaces when they are out of the screen.
Destruction of controllable cude is done in that same cube so there shoudn't be anything that is destroyed with it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that obstacle disappeared not because it was destroyed.
Something was wrong with rendering.
Changing sorting layer for obstacle or setting higher order in default layer fixes the problem.

I am curious why it even happens because sorting layer of the obstacle is not being updated after the collision and still it was disappearing.

Also only last obstacles were disappearing.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should have been able to determine when making a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example before posting your question. A minimal example would omit any background objects the obstacle could get sorted behind. The reason we ask you to do this is that we won't be able to help you solve problems unless all the potential contributing factors are documented in your question, and your question does not document how the sorting layers are configured for the background and obstacle elements.